# singleTask or singleInstance in games - Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

My question is really short.
I have a game which has a reset class that resets all the objects.
If I understand it correctly I only need one instance of the game activity at the same time.
Since if Android created multiple instances of the activity it would be a waste of resources.

Is the changing of launchMode in Android a way to achieve this. Is it safe to use launchMode="singleInstance" to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the answer at [Android singleTask or singleInstance launch mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode) - which does a good job if explaining the documentation and refers on to an excellent blog / android app (at http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/02/17/android-activites-and-tasks-series-an-introduction-to-androids-ui-component-model/).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what launchMode="singleInstance" does, but you could achieve what you are trying to do by using the Singleton Pattern:

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-singleton-design-pattern

Answer (score 2):

I think [singleTop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) is what you are looking for. singleTask and singleInstance should only be used in rare cases.

Answer (score 2):

If i'm right, `singleTop` will do the thing only if you have only 1 `Activity` so it's always on the top of the stack. Otherwise you can try to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag while sending an intent.