# Single Instance of Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, notifications

My application has three activities say `A -> B-> C`.

Activity A is called from another activity through `startActivityForResult()`. Activity B and C are also called similarly. I have to call activity A from notifications bar also (if there is some specific notification).

Now, if currently I am in activity B or C, and I click on Notification bar, and call the activity A, the app goes to Activity A only and data entered through activites B or C do not persist.

I don't want such behavior. I want that if I click on Notification, it should redirect to current screen only. Can some one help. (I mentioned `activity:launchMode` as `SingleTask`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use a static variable to determine other data. I am not sure how much or what type of data you are looking to access from the other Activities, though.

Also writing to persistent storage may work, but again - the vagueness of what data you are storing and how makes it difficult to answer. Just write/read the persistent storage in the `onResume` and `onSuspend` methdod of each Activity (or create super Activity class and extend it for A, B and C.

Comment: That also does not worked for me. Sorry for getting so long time in response

Comment: No that does not work, so we changed the design of our app.
Any ways Thank you so much

Answer (score 20):

Using `android:launchMode="singleTask"` is probably the best approach, since it won't recreate the activity if it's already running.  Just add it to the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, and you should be all set.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Here's another question that might be useful: [Android singleTask or singleInstance launch mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode)

Comment: no it does not works. I tried alot but mentioning simply single task, is not workin