# Avoiding multiple instances of an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I simply want that my activity has only one instance. I read about intent flags and launchmodes, but it just refuses to work.
I tried SingleTask, SingleTop, various intent flags etc. etc. 
My manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.secret.domain.Player"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_player" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
    </activity>
```

and the launch code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Player.class);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,s);
intent.setData( Uri.parse( s ));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

The Player activity obviously plays music, and still does it if I go back and create a new instance, both can play at the same time. OnNewIntent() is never called by the way.

 I assume I've did something wrong, but I cant find out what.

EDIT: I know it sounds similar to other threads, but I read them and still couldn't figure out how to achieve what I want.

Comment: Also check this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706645/single-instance-of-activity

Comment: I don't think that the problem in the Player `Activity`. Do you handle `onNewIntent()` there and what component do you use to play your music?

Comment: I use MediaPlayer for playing (in Player), onNewIntent() is never called at all - so I don't handle anything there.

Answer (score 0):

So you have made a shot to your leg, he he )))

As your activity should be run in single task (because of `singleTask` attribute). Every time when you start it, the system creates a new task for your `Activity` retaining the previous instance and it's media player component in memory.

That's why you hear several music tracks from several created tasks.

In such situation you may either make `Activity` to be as a `singleInstance` (using appropriate attribute in manifest), then if you already have created task with `Activity` in it, you just will need to handle intent in `onNewIntent()` and you should start it without any `Intent` flags. But you should make this `Activity` to have `ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` filters as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Starting) in the second paragraph. Or you should make it `standard` in your manifest and launch it with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` considering that you will lose all the top activities.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either. By the way, I can't do the filters as described, it's not a stand alone activity (and it doesn't work as desired)

Comment: So you want to say, that if you specify your activity in the manifest as `standard` and start it with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` intent flag, you don't get the result that you want?

Comment: Yep, I still get multiple instances.

Comment: Then override `onDestroy()` and turn off the music player there. If I understand documentation correctly, with `standard` launch mode, the `Activity` will be also removed from stack when start the new one, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) Note: If the launch mode of the designated activity is "standard", it too is removed from the stack and a new instance is launched in its place to handle the incoming intent. That's because a new instance is always created for a new intent when the launch mode is "standard".

Comment: I tried almost every launchmode/flag combination and it still didn't work. The onDestroy() approach would stop playback - I don't want this.
Edit: To make it clearer, said Player should play in background (more or less), if I hit the play button (in the library) again, I don't want a new Player, but get back to the old one.