# What is launchMode really?

Tags: android

The manual is not enough:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Is there an article with examples somewhere that is less encyclopedic and more story-like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer at [Android singleTask or singleInstance launch mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode) - which does a good job of explaining the documentation and refers on to an excellent blog / android app (at http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/02/17/android-activites-and-tasks-series-an-introduction-to-androids-ui-component-model/).