# TabGroupActivity startChildActivity - pause currentActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, childactivity

Extending TabGroupActivity, when I start a new childActivity:

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        activityIdList.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

How can I put the current activity into the pause state?

Because after I start a child activity in this way, when I restart it, then the on create method is run. How can I avoid this?

Found one solution is to use another flag:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
```

but not sure if it is the best solution

P.P.S
Another solution is to add an boolean intent to the startChildActivity method:

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
    intent.addExtra("resume", true);
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        activityIdList.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

and then retrieve it from the child activity and check if the activity is restarted or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in activity tag in the manifest file

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

It should look something like this

```
<activity android:name=".dashboard.DashboardActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Comment: Great! But what is the difference between single task and single instance?

Comment: This is a good read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode.