# How to enable only one instance of my application

Tags: android, installation, single-instance

I need only one instance of my app in android. If I run my app after installation and go to Home screen, and again run my app (click on app's icon), second instance is opened, I need to open already running first instance not to run second instance. I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` or `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in your manifest.xml in your `activity` tag

Comment: What is difference of singleTask and singleInstance?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode

Comment: @Zapnologica It is too late but on your Launcher activity.