# Android: Use running MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I' developing an Android app and in this app I've got a Android MediaPlayer and I want to ask, if I can access with this MediaPlayer to a running MediaPlayer, that was started by an other app?

For example I start a song with the Android Music app and the user opens my app. Is there a method to access and control this stream of the Android Music? So I can stop the music with stop() and start it start() and all the other functions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if there's a way to control a Media Player running in some other app from your app, then no. There is no way to do that.

If the other app is a **service** though, and that service allows control over its media player through intents, then you could control the other media player, but I'd be surprised if you got that lucky.

Comment: Okay, and what is if this other app is my own app? in my case it is that my app starts a stream in MediaPlayer and when I close the app and want to open the app again, the stream goes on but it doesn't resume in the app, it restarts it (yes it is a bug, but I don't get a solution). and because of this bug, I want that the app doesn't create a new MediaPlayer in the onCreate() method and takes the still running stream. You know what I mean?

Comment: I think I understand. It doesn't matter if its your app or not. If the system starts 2 of your app, you still can't communicate between them easily. Its possible but that is not a good solution here. The solution is to fix the bug causing multiple instances to run. [Check this link for help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467802/how-to-enable-only-one-instance-of-my-application)

Comment: Okay, thank you. But the launchMode singleTask and singleInstance create a new task on launch, don't they? And this brings the same problem like a already have, doesn't it? I saw this image http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_JHMkMKLWbtQ/TRjJhg0y6TI/AAAAAAAAH3U/KJRovtfL2Ds/s1600/Untitled-1.png Or do I understand it in the wrong way?