# android press home button and re-enter my application

Tags: android, android-homebutton

In my app, my own Application class saved some static variables, after clicked home button in my application, the screen go back to home. now i want to resume my application, when i click my app icon in launcher, the variables of the variables before are null, but onlongclick home button and choose my application, the variables is normal~

Comment: Since every device can behave differently, in your case, what does long clicking the home button do? Also, might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle-application-act-crazy/1944564#1944564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click app icon from the launcher at that time second instance generated for your app.To solve this issue you have to manage with single instance. For that you can use

> **android:launchMode="singleTask**"   or
>
> **android:launchMode="singleInstance**"

` in your manifest for activity

Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467802/how-to-enable-only-one-instance-of-my-application) too