# Go back to previous screen without creating new instance

Tags: android

[image]

As explained in image, flow is something like this. So whenever user click on logo button Activity A should be called. As simple solution we can use this method...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityToStart);
startActivity(intent);
```

But this activity will create a new activity for my app. but I need to call the same instance of the activity as we move forward in flow diagram. from Activity A to B and then again on B can be called easily by calling`finish()` but from Activity C or D, how to come back to A.

I am running out of ideas but not getting any fruitful result. Please help me if you have any suggestion or at any place i am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To Come Back from D to A, use Intent Flags.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityToStart);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent);
```

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, will instead of creating new activity, it will invoke the activity on the stack, and will pop all the activities over the activity being invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityToStart);
startActivity(intent);
```

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityToStart);
startActivityforResult(intent,1234);
```

This will make Sure that The Activity A is not Killed and when You finish Your Activity C,Activity A will get Resumed.

**Note** :- Whenever You create A new Activity,without finishing(Exiting) the Host Activity,The Host Activity is Saved On the Stack in LIFO order

**LIFO**:- `Last In First Out`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will definitely try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

By making Activity A a "SingleTask" you can achive this. When a Activity is in the SingleTask on clicking the Home button the other activites will be removed from the stack.

Refer these link's for more info on Android Activites...

[Link 1 - Android Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

[Link 2 - Another Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668144/about-android-launchmode-singletask/11669073#11669073)

Comment: Don;t you think this way I won't be able to achieve back button functionality. Thanks any ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewFlipper to go and back between different window in the same activity.

```
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById( R.id.view_flipper);
```

To go to the next window

```
vf.showNext();
```

To go to the previous window

```
vf.showPrevious();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure,this is right way or not,but you can give it a try!

You can finish() current activity when you open the new one starting from Activity-B.

i.e.

To open Activity-C => finish Activity-B and start Activity-C

To open Activity-D => finish Activity-C and start Activity-D

now when you will press back,Activity-A will open.

Comment: Thanks. I will try as per your suggestion