# How can my application return to previous activity without calling oncreate

Tags: android

I have main activity that have grid of images and details activity which display one image.  When you click on image of main activity the app launch the detail activity with the selected image. I want to return from details activity to the main activity without calling on create of the main activity because it consumes a lot of time. How can I do that ?

I use

```
 Intent in = new Intent(Search_costumer.this,Customer_details.class);
    startActivity(in);
```

to navigate from the main activity to the details activity

Comment: if u press back button on detail activity, it will never called oncreate() of your main activity. it will start from onresme().

Comment: the app always go to on Create method of the main activity

Comment: and how you are coming back on search_costumer activity?

Answer (score 1):

Use Bundle `savedInstanceState` because its maintain state of your activity like `Bluetooth` once its `ON` after switch off your phone its still On.Somewhere Its maintain its `status(On/OFF)`.

Answer (score 0):

when you are switching to details activity donot finish your main activity and when you return from there onResume will get called and not onCreate

Comment: I use  Intent in = new Intent(Search_costumer.this,Customer_details.class);
    startActivity(in);

Answer (score -1):

When you start your DetailsActivty, **Do not call finish()** from MainActivity. 
This will not destroy your MainActvity and when you click back button from DetailsActivity, onResume() will be called for MainActivity. 
You can take help of this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715848/go-back-to-previous-screen-without-creating-new-instance).

Hope this help, if any confusion feel free to ask

Comment: I use  Intent in = new Intent(Search_costumer.this,Customer_details.class);
    startActivity(in);