# Activity flow: clicking on my app icon will onCreate MainActivity

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-lifecycle, intentfilter, launchmode

In my app, I navigate from MainActivity to Activity B. I then press the HOME button and then click on the app icon again to maximize it.

Instead of onResuming my Activity B, it goes back to MainActivity.

This makes sense because in my AndroidManifest.xml, I'm using the normal intent-filters to launch the MainActivity when you click on its icon:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

I was checking popular apps like facebook and twitter, none of them seem to experience this problem - when you navigate from your facebook feed to a friends page and then press the HOME button. Then you click on the app icon again and it is still on your friend's page.

This only seems to affect the app when I click on the app icon. If for example go from MainActivity to Activity B, press HOME button and then press the SQUARE button to show all my apps running in the background, select my app that is in the background to maximize it again, the app will return back correctly to Activity B.

How do I make sure that when you click on the **app icon**, it `onResumes` Activity B instead?

Comment: Remove android:launchMode="singleTask" from your Manifest. Description here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Add if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) ==
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) {
    finish();
} in your MainActivity's onCreate();

Comment: The launchtask was set like that because I'm integrating deeplinks which will not work if I remove it. Nonetheless I will still try it out later and get back to u. I will also try out ur suggestion tiny sunlight.

Comment: Febi M Felix will you please convert your comment into an answer. Your suggestion is correct and my app now works as intended.

Comment: Does this also happen if you force stop the app and then start it again by clicking on the app icon on the home screen? If not, You are probably seeing this nasty Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265

Comment: @Simon How did you handle deeplinks if you removed singletask, its necessary for deeplinks

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove `android:launchMode="singleTask"` from manifest

From [Android launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) doc,

> "singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task.
> They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the
> device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one
> such task.

From [Android back stack singleTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) doc,

> The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the
> root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already
> exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the
> existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather
> than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can
> exist at a time.
>
> Note: Although the activity starts in a new task, the Back button
> still returns the user to the previous activity.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I already have a clear understanding of the activity lifecycle which is why I asked this question in the first place. Other people, Facebook, twitter have managed to over come this problem and now I want to know how. This is not an answer to solving my problem.

Comment: Remove android:launchMode="singleTask" from manifest. See edited answer

Comment: Also study this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668144/about-android-launchmode-singletask

Comment: Deeplink handling will be broken if we remove single task. How to acheive this?

Comment: @abhishekmaharajpet You got any updates? I've the same issue with Deeplink.