# Restarting Activity from IntentService if Activity is running

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice

I have a `Activity` and a `IntentService`

the `Activity` calls the `IntentService` and when the `IntentService` has finished I want to restart the Activity. But only if it is currently on screen. when it is opened again (only `onResume()`) called, and no new instance created, it should also restart.

So what is the best way to practice this?

Answer (score 0):

If the activity is still on screen you don't have to restart it. You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` that will handle a broadcast sent when your `IntentService` has finished its work.

If the activity has finished or is not on screen, it is safe (and not a bad practice) to use `startActivity` and create a new instance. It will make your history consistent.

If you really want to have one and only instance of your activity you can add the following line to your activity tag in the manifest.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

or

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220375/990616) explains the difference if you want to learn the details.

Comment: the problem is, that I have to restart the Activity because the Layout is generated by code and it have to load the new data from the database because I'm not able to find the explicit views I want. And when the user has exit the app the intentservice is still running and doing his work. and the user get a notification when the intentservice has finished. so I don't want to annoy the user to start my app when he is currently in another one so it would be a bad practise I think.