# Within Android, how do I start an activity or bring to front that activity if already on stack?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent

Within Android, how do I start an activity or bring to front that activity if already on stack?

So far I know start a new activity *myActivity*, as by the code below shows. But I don't want to open a second copy of the same class, if it's already open on the stack. So how do I check whether activities like the below exist on the stack, then if it exists bring it to front. If it doesn't, open a new activity like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this,
        myActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flag in your intent when you want to start new Activity

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this,
        myActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Just to confirm, will that bring an activity to the front if it exists. But if it doesn't, create a new

Comment: exactly. play with those flags a bit to see what kind of results you can get

Comment: No, that still seems to create new items in the stack at times when  one already exists

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this,
        myActivity.class);
 intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have several processes running or other instances of the Activity started through other calls to start the Activity.

You are probably needing to specify in the manifest either "singleInstance" or "singleTask" -

[Android singleTask or singleInstance launch mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode)

Word of caution - this may have some other unintended side effects. Just be sure to test it for different use-cases.