# How to get past Android manifest without a public constructor?

Tags: android, xml, constructor, android-manifest

In my manifest I have this:

```
<activity
  android:name=".BackgroundOptionSlider"
  android:label="@string/update_background" >
</activity>
```

but my class, `BackgroundOptionsSlider`, need to have a private default constructor for what I am doing (making sure there is only one instance ever) and for this reason I am getting an error in my manifest's stating that I need to have a  public default constructor. How can I get past this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `BackgroundOptionSlider` extends an `Activity`, you can't avoid having a default public constructor.

> making sure there is only one instance ever

The way to accomplish this is already given to you by the system, declare

```
<activity
        android:name=".BackgroundOptionSlider"
        android:label="@string/update_background"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
    </activity>
```

OR

```
<activity
        android:name=".BackgroundOptionSlider"
        android:label="@string/update_background"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    </activity>
```

[More information](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) about the launch mode, and also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

You should never try to instantiate the Activity by yourself the android framework does that for you so you should  provide a default public constructor,If  you want to have only single instance of an activity you can achieve that by specifying the launch mode as singleInstance, [here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en) here is a good read about launchModes