# Deal with not working animations when activity is SingleInstance

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I am developing an android app and I have used `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` for it,but as I activated it none of `TransitionAnimation` works and it makes my activity like this

[image]

In fact my main activity is singleinstane and when I want to lunch a new activity the new one does not work and ui breaks. well what can I do with it?Is there any way to have animations while singleinstace is activated?
this is my code which lunches activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityMall.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putParcelable("EXTRA_MALL",((Mall)v.getTag(R.id.TAG_MALL_ID)));
                b.putParcelable("EXTRA_Company",null);
                intent.putExtras(b);

                ActivityOptionsCompat options =
                        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context,
                                (View)v.getTag(R.id.TAG_MALL_COVER2),   // Starting view
                                "profile1"    // The String
                                            );
                ActivityCompat.startActivity((Activity) context, intent, options.toBundle());
```

I read somewhere that I should set `android:launchMode="singleTask"` but I have no idea about its difference with singleinstance..
thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29741591/3024565).

**SingleInstance** is same as **singleTask**, except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task; any activities started by this one open in a separate task.

Go ahead and use "singleTask" as launchMode your app will work fine.