# Android: when should I use singleInstance launchmode

Tags: android, launchmode

There are four launch modes for an Activity, standard, singletop, singletask, and singleInstance. The previous three are relatively easy understanding and widely used. But till now, I did not find any scenario using singleInstance.

> [Some of the real use case is an Activity for Launcher or the application that you are 100% sure there is only one Activity](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Have any one used it before?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode

Comment: This might help : [Understand Android Activity's launchMode: standard, singleTop, singleTask and singleInstance](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Answer (score 3):

There is never a reason to use `singleInstance` launch mode.

If you are building a "home screen" replacement or a launcher type application, you would use `singleInstance` or `singleTask` launch mode to ensure that your `Activity` is always the root of its task. This makes sure that if another application launches your `Activity`, that `Activity` does not get launched into the task of the calling application and it also ensures that there is only ever one instance of your `Activity` created.

If you are writing a "home screen" replacement application, you can always make sure that no other activities get launched into your own task by always specifiying `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when launching other activities. In that case, you can use launch mode `singleTask`. So there is no reason to use launch mode `singleInstance`. But it probably wasn't clear to the original developers of Android at the time.

Comment: i used singleInstance and i want's clear that activity from backstack than what can i do ????

Comment: @SagarPoshiya Please open a new question and describe your problem. Asking a question in a comment here is not the right way to get help.

Answer (score 1):

SingleInstance launch mode should only be used in the applications that are implemented entirely as one activity.
Only one instance will exist at a time. System will not launch any other activity into task holding this type. It is always a single member of its task and activities started from here will open into seperate task.

Comment: You don't need to use `singleInstance` launch mode to get this behaviour. Standard launch mode should give you this behaviour as well. In general it is a bad idea to use `singleInstance` launch mode unless you are building a "home screen" replacement.

Answer (score -2):

singleInstance launchmode will be used when you do not want any **other activity** to be a part of the task.Its the **only** activity in the task.
As this launchmode does not permit that.

Comment: I don't really think this answers the question. It is too long and boring for me to even look at it to see if it is correct or not, but it doesn't answer OP's question, which is _"When should I use `singleInstance` launch mode?"_

Comment: Edited answer.Check once again.

Comment: Ok, why do you need to have only one activity in the task? Still does not answer the question :)