# Usage of "Single Instance" and "SingleTask" in Android

Tags: android

I know what is the difference between in "Singletask" and "SingleInstance" But I just want to know in which circumstance should be use "Singletask" and in which condition use "SingleInstance".All answer are same i did not satisfaction.Please explain with demo as soon as possible.Please tell me which problem will face without using each other.

Comment: `as soon as possible` ... in general you should avoid saying something is urgent, unless it really is, and even then you should give a valid reason why the community should rush to help you.

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en very good explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android singleTask or singleInstance launch mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode)