# Handle an Activity that is pushed to the foreground

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listen to ActivityManager events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272168/listen-to-activitymanager-events)

Is it possible to know immediately (not by listing / iterating over processes in the background service with intervals) which app (and which activity) has been pushed to the front, perhaps using some kind of broadcast information? I want to know globally which app has been pushed to the front, not just for activities within my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible, at least not without modifying the Android source. Take a look at the source of [`ApplicationsProvider`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/providers/applications/ApplicationsProvider.java).

This is a similar question: [Listen to ActivityManager events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272168/listen-to-activitymanager-events)