# How to detect a specific application has started in android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

i want to detect that some application has started in android, such as when you have started YouTube application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272168/listen-to-activitymanager-events read more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you think of using a `service` that would be running all the time in background and would send a broadcast for the current running application.

Hope this thread solves your problem somehow.

[Determining the current foreground application from a background task or service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2166961/1503130)